# wp_get_nav_menu_items order doesn't work

Tags: menus

I am using this function

```
$args = array (
   'order' => 'DESC',
);

$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $custom_menu, $args );
```

then, if I change args to

```
$args = array (
   'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

and the result is still the same.

Anybody have suggestion?

Comment: maybe `'order_by' => 'menu_order'` parameter triggers conflict

Comment: @TweetPressFr: 'orderby'=>'menu_order' is default value for this param (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items#Parameters)

Comment: and so? I already know what you're saying and I was implying it could trigger conflicts

Answer (score 3):

When you look in WordPress source code, you will find reason for that. On line 538 of nav-menu.php you'll find:

```
if ( ARRAY_A == $args['output'] ) {
    $GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop'] = $args['output_key'];
        usort($items, '_sort_nav_menu_items');
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $items as $k => $item ) {
            $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++;
        }
}
```

I didn't check why, but it looks like this sorting doesn't work right. The easiest thing you can do to fixthis is to change output type to disable this sorting.

So when you add `'output'=>OBJECT` or `'output'=>ARRAY_N` to your args it should work just fine.

PS. It's even known bug: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15533

Comment: I've added 'output' => OBJECT to the args but nothing happens

Comment: So you have `$args = array('order'=>'DESC', 'output'=>OBJECT);` now? Items should be sorted correctly with this change. You can also try `'output'=>ARRAY_N`.

Comment: Works for me. Here is my code. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159089/get-wp-get-nav-menu-items-to-sort-alphabetically/159364 Didnt find this one before posting

Comment: If it is not working - consider my mistake:
I was thinking that it would order by my order of the post type itsself. What's actually is happening, is that it is ordering by the menus order, not the posts order themselves. This actually makes sense, if you think about it.