# Get "wp_get_nav_menu_items" to sort alphabetically

Tags: sort

I am trying to return a menu in alphabetical order and not the order set by the user in the backend. I have this code but it is not alphabetical:

```
$args = array(
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'title',);
$menu= wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id, $args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no idea why I got a negative vote on this. Turns out this is actually a bug in wordpress: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15533

The solution is to use "object" instead of "array".

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'output' => object);
```

Hope it helps someone else.